# Cannot increment returned sregex_iterator?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to construct an sregex_iterator from some complicated computations so I wrote a function to do this and return the iterator. However when I then want to increment the returned iterator, the program crashes, sometimes throwing std::bad_alloc, sometimes not..

I managed to reduce it to a MWE with little code but somehow I still cannot figure out what is happening..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

sregex_iterator get_it(const string& str) {
    regex r("([ab]{3})");

    auto it = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r);
    cout << (it == sregex_iterator() ? "end\n" : "more\n");
    ++it; //works as expected .. no crash. When commented out, program still crashes
    cout << "can incr ..\n";

    return it;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto it = get_it("aaa bbb");
    cout << (it == sregex_iterator() ? "end\n" : "more\n");
    ++it; //this crashes the program

    cout << "success\n"; // never runs
}
```

To compile I use g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0 with `-std=c++11` flag.

This runs and outputs

```
more
can incr ..
more
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

So increment works in the function where I construct the iterator, but not outside. But all that happens is copy (/move if RVO happens) of the iterator, which should not invalidate it?
Surely the `sregex_iterator` does not store reference or pointer to any of its constructed-from arguments?

My only guess is there must be a ref/ptr to temporary somewhere but I do not see it.. or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `sregex_iterator` *does* store a pointer to the constructed-from regex.

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the std::basic_regex object passed to the iterator's constructor outlives the iterator. Because the iterator stores a pointer to the regex, incrementing the iterator after the regex was destroyed accesses a dangling pointer.

from cppreference. This seems unfortunate ..., but I guess I can return the regex instead of the iterator.

Curious with regex being C++11 and not having a move constructor instead, but I see this was added with C++14 .. maybe time to update.